# How to Display the same passed variables on the crystal report using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I'm really sure that the title of my question depicts what i mean.i guess that's why i can't find that much on google.I think it needs to be explained.
Basically i've manage to pass programmatically discrete values to my report successfully.
Now i wanted to make use of the A4 paper format to have 2 A3 format.that means i want to have twice the display of the report.So i naively copy what i already did to the bottom of the report.The duplicated ones are not displaying for some reason.
The only workaround i can find is to create same set of parameters with different names and pass the same values to them.But that doesn't sound good to me and there are about 12 parameters.It should just be 24 if i want to do that.How you guys solve this?
Thanks for reading.
PS: using C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you right click and choose Format Field and see if the "Suppress" or "Suppress if duplicated" field is ticked?

Comment: thanks for you reply, and sorry for the late comment. Actually the crystal report had a funny behavior i didn't understood.In fact i created a second details section .So i found out that it's the whole section b that wasn't showing when i drag something from section a to section b and vice versa.to be honest i don't know what i did to make it appear :) .it's fine now thanks again